# Manipulate a file before provisioning in terraform

Tags: templates, terraform, file-copying, terraform-provider-aws

So I have created a terraform script that does the following:

1. Spins up an EC2 instance
2. Copies over some files
3. Run some remote commands to install stuff from repos
4. Creates an elasticsearch service domain

Now I need to configure the ec2 instance with the endpoint I get back from elasticsearch domain, so the application are using the right endpoint (currently it has some default value).

How can I pass the endpoint value into the file and then copy it over to the ec2 instance. What would be the recommended approach?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This as pretty broad.. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am already using file provisioning to copy over local files to the ec2 instance. What I am really after, is some way to change the application configuration file before sending the file over to the ec2 instance.
If I would translate this to salt stack, I would like to achieve the same as using jinja templates when using the managed file functions. Basically changing parts of the file content based on variables.

Comment: Terraform's focus is a bit more on the infrastructure level, not so much operating system and application config. You can execute shell commands and use the good old `sed`, `grep` etc. friends.

Comment: Using `remote-exec`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Terraform will derive the order automatically, when you refer to the output of a certain resource. You can use the [`file` provisioner](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/file.html) to create files on the EC2 instance.

Comment: Can a file provisioning also replace parts of the file content?

Comment: Not that I know of.

Answer (score 0):

If the EC2 instances don't need to be created prior to the Elasticsearch domain, you can use the [template](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/template/index.html) provider and render the file based on the values of the Elasticsearch resource, render and copy up to the EC2 instances.